# regexextract isn't working the way I want in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

...or rather...there's something wrong with my formula.

I have a series of item numbers, and I want to extract *only* the info between the first and 3rd dash, if any.

The info before the 1st dash *must* be letters.
The info between the 1st and second dash *must* be letters (i.e. A-z).
The info between the 2nd and 3rd dash *must* be numbers.
I want everything else to be ignored (I've wrapped my regexextract in an iferror to do this)

Here's my formula:

```
=arrayformula(iferror(regexextract(B1:B,"[A-z]+-([A-Z\{\\\]\^_`a-z]+-[0-9]+)-"),"")
```

It's working most of the time.

But for this: AAB-2971-PN-B-11-03
It extracts this: B-11
But I'm expecting this one to be an error/blank.

Other *correct* examples:
AAB-LL-1234-00  should extract  LL-1234
AAN-1234  should error out
AAC-1234-LL  should error out
AAC-1234-ll-123  should error out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
[A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+-([0-9]+)-
```

And extract group `2`.

There are a few problems with your regex, but the main one is `[A-z]` does not mean "all letters", it means "all characters between `A` and `z`", which includes the characters between `Z` and `a`, ie `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_` and the back tick.

I suspect  `[A-Z{\]\^_`a-z]+`is your attempt at`[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right: [A-Z{\]\^_a-z]+is your attempt at[A-Za-z].

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(B1:B, "-"),,2)&"", "\D+")&
 REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX("-"&SPLIT(B1:B, "-"),,3), "-\d+")))
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF((REGEXMATCH(INDEX(SPLIT(B1:B, "-"),,1), "[A-Za-z]+"))*
 (NOT(REGEXMATCH(INDEX(SPLIT(B1:B, "-"),,1), "[0-9]+"))), 
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(B1:B, "-"),,2)&"", "\D+")&
  REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX("-"&SPLIT(B1:B, "-"),,3), "-\d+")), )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I was trying to keep the formula "purely" regex, but I like the idea of using the Split function to help.